# Check if a column is auto increment with ODBC?

Tags: c++, sql, odbc, auto-increment

Is there a way to know using C++ and ODBC API if a table (defined by its schema and table) has column with auto-sequence property (AKA identity property) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually how to access the table schema is a server specific implementation detail. The schema might be represented from further special tables that can be accessed in the connected database. How these are named is not standardized IIRC.

Comment: We can't use the function SQLColAttribute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx with field identifier SQL_DESC_AUTO_UNIQUE_VALUE to retrieve this information?

Comment: Well, it's SQL Server specific. Do you want to retag your question?

Comment: I would prefer if it is generic. But I am curious to know the specific way for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `SQLSpecialColumns` function. It provides a list of columns that are automatically updated when any value in the row is updated by a transaction.

Comment: Finally I used Specific processing for every DBMS.

For example for MySQL I used the query:
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table' AND EXTRA = 'auto_increment'",

Comment: Seems like you weren't interested in a c++ solution. Maybe retag the question?

Comment: SQLSpecialColumns didn't work for me. I used SQLExecDirect with appropriate Query according the SQL DBMS type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQLColAttribute with field identifier parameter SQL_DESC_AUTO_UNIQUE_VALUE
as in this function

```
int fetch_identity(const std::string& sql, int& is_identity)
    {
      SQLHSTMT hstmt;
      is_identity = 0;
      SQLCHAR         colname[32];        // column name
      SQLSMALLINT     coltype;            // column type
      SQLSMALLINT     colnamelen;         // length of column name
      SQLSMALLINT     nullable;           // whether column can have NULL value
      SQLULEN         collen;             // column length
      SQLSMALLINT     decimaldigits;      // no of digits if column is numeric
      SQLLEN          auto_unique_value;;
      SQLINTEGER      idx;
      SQLSMALLINT     nbr_cols;

      if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, query.m_hdbc, &hstmt)))
      {
      }

      if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)sql.c_str(), SQL_NTS)))
      {
        extract_error(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
      }

      // Get number of nbr_cols from prepared statement
      if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLNumResultCols(hstmt, &nbr_cols)))
      {
        extract_error(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
      }

      for (idx = 0; idx < nbr_cols; idx++)
      {
        // for each column from the prepared statement in hstmt, get the
        // column name, type, column size, decimal digits, and nullability
        if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLDescribeCol(hstmt,
          (SQLUSMALLINT)idx + 1,
          colname,
          sizeof(colname),
          &colnamelen,
          &coltype,
          &collen,
          &decimaldigits,
          &nullable)))
        {
          extract_error(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
        }

        auto_unique_value = 0;

        //SQL_DESC_AUTO_UNIQUE_VALUE
        //FieldIdentifier parameter returned in NumericAttributePtr
        //SQL_TRUE if the column is an autoincrementing column.
        //SQL_FALSE if the column is not an autoincrementing column or is not numeric.

        if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLColAttribute(hstmt,
          (SQLUSMALLINT)idx + 1,
          SQL_DESC_AUTO_UNIQUE_VALUE,
          NULL,
          0,
          NULL,
          &auto_unique_value)))
        {
          extract_error(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
        }
        if (auto_unique_value == 1)
        {
          is_identity = 1;
        }
      }

      SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
      return 0;
    }
```

variable m_hdbc is described here

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_odbc